# Gridview Control Sorting Direction

Tags: asp.net, gridview

The default sorting order on the gridview control is ascending first, then descending. Now below I have code to change that around. So far so good. But when I click on another column again, it sets the sort direction to ascending again. It alternates between descending and ascending on every click, no matter which column. Now what I really want is for the first click on any column to be descending, and if I click any column for the second time(second time meaning consecutively), it should be ascending. Example: I have 2 columns, one is salary and the other is age. Now I click on salary, and the first sorting direction is descending, not the default ascending(that's what the code does). Now when I click on age, it switches the sorting direction to ascending, I want it to stay the same when I change to another column, BUT should I click on salary again for the second time, it should switch to ascending(cause descending was the first click). Any suggestions?

My code:

```
public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null) 
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
        return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; 
    }
}
protected void GridView1_OnSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
    {
        e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
    }
    else if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
    }
    else if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Descending)
    {
        e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
    }

    GridViewSortDirection = e.SortDirection;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking to determine whether the SortExpression has changed from the previously set SortExpression and if so default the SortDirection to Descending.

```
protected void GridView1_OnSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SortExpression != GridView1.SortExpression)
    {
        e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
        GridViewSortDirection = e.SortDirection;
    }
    else if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
    }
    else if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Descending)
    {
        e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
    }

    GridViewSortDirection = e.SortDirection;
}
```

Comment: I assume this part you suggested :                                  if (e.SortExpression != GridView1.SortExpression)
    {
        e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
    }                                                                    should just be added to my code , the first thing in the- protected void GridView1_OnSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)?
statement

Comment: cause I'm not sure since I got that code of mine from another forum discussion. I understand only half of the code really.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your above code. It should work, however I have not been able to test it.

Comment: ah great man, thank you! Works like a charm. I really appreciate your help, you saved me a lot of time and keybords. (still learning functions)

Comment: I kinda get the code except for the crucial part:                 if (e.SortExpression != GridView1.SortExpression)
    {
        e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
        GridViewSortDirection = e.SortDirection;
    }
What does the above part do and mean?

Comment: The `if (e.SortExpression != GridView1.SortExpression)` statement is checking to determine whether the active sort expression is different from any previous sort expression. If this is the case then this signals that a new column is being sorted and the sort direction is set to descending rather than the default (ascending). The GridViewSortDirection property is then updated ready for subsequent checks. Hope this helps.